# Что такое zstring в C++ и где его взять?

Tags: c++, строки

В [одном из разделов](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rstr-zstring) Cpp core guidlines говорится о загадочных строковых типах `zstring` и `czstring` и преимуществах их использования перед классическими `char *`. Не смог найти ничего подобного в C++. Подскажите, как подключить и использовать эти типы в своих программах?

P.S. Я знаю, что для хранения строк ещё лучше подойдёт `std::string`. Интересуюсь только лишь из любопытства, а не с целью практического использования.

Comment: Гугление приводит к [Guidelines Support Library](https://github.com/microsoft/GSL) от Microsoft.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это типы из библиотеки Guidelines Support Library (есть [реализация](https://github.com/microsoft/GSL) от Microsoft). Использовать GSL в этой реализации достаточно просто — вся библиотека находится в заголовочных файлах, так что линковать ее не нужно. Достаточно просто скачать из репозитория директорию `include/gsl/` и скопировать в папку со своим проектом. Затем прописать путь к заголовочным файлам в настройках компилятора. Для GCC и Clang, например, это будет выглядеть так:

```
clang -I"include/" ...
```

Документации я не нашел (может, плохо искал), поэтому о типах можно узнать прямо из заголовочных файлов (нас интересует `string_span.h`):

> ```
> //
> // czstring and wzstring
> //
> // These are "tag" typedefs for C-style strings (i.e. null-terminated character arrays)
> // that allow static analysis to help find bugs.
> //
> // There are no additional features/semantics that we can find a way to add inside the
> // type system for these types that will not either incur significant runtime costs or
> // (sometimes needlessly) break existing programs when introduced.
> //
>
> template <typename CharT, std::ptrdiff_t Extent = dynamic_extent>
> using basic_zstring = CharT*;
>
> template <std::ptrdiff_t Extent = dynamic_extent>
> using czstring = basic_zstring<const char, Extent>;
>
> ...
>
> template <std::ptrdiff_t Extent = dynamic_extent>
> using zstring = basic_zstring<char, Extent>;
> ```

Используем примерно так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <gsl/gsl>

int main()
{
    gsl::czstring<> s = "hello, world!\n";
    std::cout << s;
}
```